# License problem in Spain

Tags: license, europe

I am from the UK and live in the Canary Islands. I am told I have to take my ham radio license test in Spanish, but I don't speak Spanish. Is there a way around this somehow? Maybe take the UK one (online) or another one in an English speaking country and transfer it to a Spanish license?

Answer (score 8):

[Spain accepts the HAREC Certificate and licences from Argentina, Australia, Brasil, Canada, Colombia, Costa Rica, United States of America and Venezuela](https://www.ure.es/licensing-and-basic-info-for-visitor-hams/) as equivalent to passing Spanish radio licensing exams.

A UK Full licence is a HAREC Certificate; you can also get HAREC Certificates from other countries that take part in [CEPT T/R 61-02](https://docdb.cept.org/download/2569) (notably Ireland, Malta and New Zealand, since you want to take the test in English).

Given that you can't take your local tests due to the language barrier, I'd suggest finding a country that will issue a HAREC Certificate; you will need to confirm before taking the exam that you get the HAREC as part of the exam pass, and not as part of your licence (which normally requires you to live in the country where you're licenced). In the UK, passing the RSGB Full examination [will get you both an RSGB pass certificate for use with Ofcom, and a HAREC for foreign administrations](https://rsgb.org/main/clubs-training/for-students/full/)

Comment: Simon, thanks for the info.... very helpful! still, I am struggling to find an online tester that will offer me the Harec exam without me residing in that country. My family also wish to take the exam as well.